# visual studio won't produce single file for class library

Tags: c#, publish, visual-studio-2022, class-library

Whenever I build a console application in visual studio 2022 I can select "Produce single file" in publish settings and it will produce a single .exe file without any aditional .dll files.

I would like to have the same behavior on class libraries, but the checkbox seems to be ignored. When I publish, it creates the .dll of my library but also adds all additional dlls from nuget and project reference. But I would like to have only one .dll to ship.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: You can't, it doesn't really make sense to do it it like this as a class library is not an end product. You could wrap it all up in a nuget package though.

Comment: You can change the Target runtime to e.g. win-x64. It creates a .nupkg file of the class library within the publish folder.

Comment: You can check for ILMerge https://github.com/dotnet/ILMerge, it can glue several dlls into one and can be used directly as a nugget package in your project. Edit : ha, it seems not compatible with dotnet core.

Comment: If your application reads .dll files from GAC, you will not need them in output folder. I guess that's why you will not see additional files in exe. If your project depends on libraries which are not in GAC, it will produce them in published folder. I would suggest to make a nuget package.